# Atomic Simulation Environment - GUI appears on one laptop, but not the other

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, command, gui, troubleshooting

I'm a student at University using MobaXterm to access a supercomputer cluster, which runs off of a standard UNIX BASH CLI. Within this system, and within the lab I am a member of, there is a piece of software known as the Atomic Simulation Environment (ASE), which is "a Python library for working with atoms" (for more information, see https://gitlab.com/ase/ase). It's useful because it runs in Unix as a GUI, which is much easier for the work I'm doing.

I have two machines, one is an Acer Switch 5 that I've had for a few years and the other is a Dell Latitude 5520 that the school just gave me for doing research with. The Acer has no problem opening the GUI (the command used is "ase-gui" but our lab create an alias "ag" which you'll see later). The Dell, on the other hand, simply doesn't open the GUI at all: instead, it appears to leave the GUI running in the background, forcing a manual closing of the program from the command line, and even causing the logout process to go on for a while, for when I try to log out, I get a message saying "there are stopped jobs" and typing logout a second time causes the screen to freeze for perhaps a minute before actually logging me off. See screenshot below:

[image: Manual closing of program, followed by logout difficulties]

The only thing I can think would be causing the problem is that, when I took the school laptop home, it asked the usual "Do you want this program to be accessible on public networks" or whatever that prompt which Windows pulls up from time to time says. I said no, and now I'm wondering if my school wifi is considered "private" whereas my home wifi is considered "public". Still, why would every other function of the CLI in MobaXterm be functional if this were the case?

My sincere appreciation to anyone who read all the way through. Any advice regarding the issue stated above is greatly welcome. I'm new to StackExchange, so if I'm in the wrong community or am otherwise breaking some code of etiquette, please let me know so I can make a point to not repeat the mistake in future inquiries.

Comment: Check the value of the `DISPLAY` variable in each case (`echo $DISPLAY`). Verify that X11-Forwarding is enabled in your mobaxterm session (see for example [SSH X11 Forwarding Display using MobaXterm on Windows](https://itekblog.com/ssh-x11-forwarding-display-using-mobaxterm/) ). But really this seems to be a question about Windows / mobaxterm rather than Unix & Linux.

Comment: It seems to be working now! Selecting "X11 windows with Fvwm" under the Tools tab produced that menu again, where it asked if the application should have permission to run on public, private, and/or some other third setting. I selected all three, and now ase-gui is running. Thanks! And I'll keep in mind to submit questions like this outside of the Unix/Linux Stack.